# UIView without borders

Tags: ios, uiview

I am working on something that could use from a UIView that can expand in either direction at will. Is there such a UIView in iOS? I am trying to make an app where the user will place squares on the board and depending on the situation might need to place the square either to the left, right, above or below the current square. The only way I can think of is to recreate a bigger UIView and place all the squares on it as needed. Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Your question is undefined, can you try to use a single sentence to ask your question? And that should be the title of the SO question :)

Comment: Tom - Look at Lyndsey's answer for clarity.

Comment: Hmm.  Actually I had read Lyndsey's answer 2-3 times before I commented.  Hers didn't provide clarity, I don't know why you suggest it did.  Her answer confirmed my own confusion, so I requested more clarity. Anyway what really counts is you appreciated her suggestion.  Also, "UIView without borders" is quite confusing, doesn't fit a SO question. That's confusing :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you mean by "at will"... If you mean not requiring any code, I don't think you can dynamically expand a view without code.

You could in fact expand a `UIView` programmatically though, but I'd recommend looking into using a `UIScrollView` and changing the content size programmatically if you need to place squares beyond the bounds of the screen.

Comment: Thanks! UIScrollView seems to be exactly what I am looking for. I will do a little more reading and accept the answer. And by "at will" I meant in code.